# Using an Exponent in Excel SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula, exponent, sumproduct

I am trying to replicate the NPV of cashflows but with each cash flow using different interest rates.

The following code in excel continues to produce error values:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$4:$A$1347,($B$4:$B$1347)^($C4-$C$4))
```

For reference

- Column A:the list of Cash Flows
- Column B:the discount rate
- Column C:time period

For the given data the value at time period 3 should yield:

```
=(20*(.997653^2)) + (25*(.997572^2)) + (21*(.997742^2))) + (18*(.997459^2)) + (16*(.997499^(2))
```

How can this be fixed?

[image: Example Data]

Comment: Example of reduced dataset (5-10 rows would be sufficient) plus expected results would be very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I have uploaded an image of a smaller data set with the results I would need this function to output.

Comment: Thanks. Based on that example, in `F3` it's simply `=SUMPRODUCT(A$3:A$7,B$3:B$7^(D3-1))` and copied down.